# Symfony2 image path in controller

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'd like to retrieve the `src` URL of an image.

```
{% image "@AcmeMyBundle/Resources/public/image/myimage.jpg" %}
    <img src={{ asset_url }}
{% endimage %}
```

How would I get the `asset_url` inside the controller?

e.g. `http://example.com/images/c1ca79c_myimage.jpg`

or even `images/c1ca79c__myimage.jpg`
I tried:

```
$this->container
    ->get('templating.helper.assets')
    ->getUrl('@AcmeMyBundle/Resources/public/image/myimage.jpg');
```

But this returns the string `/@AcmeMyBundle/Resources/public/image/myimage.jpg` and not a URL.

Comment: do you need `src` URL, or absolute path within a file system?

Comment: SRC URL for external linking, not the filesystem.

Comment: Just curious as to what the use case is for needing that in the controller?

Comment: @Chausser Need to forward some information to a legacy page while it's being rewritten using symfony. A section of the legacy site is functioning in Symfony2. Due to the dynamic nature of the site some image urls change which the legacy site doesn't know about. The legacy page needs these urls to function properly which is why twig is being bypassed/not used at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers were close. What I really wanted was:

```
  $this
    ->get('templating.name_parser')
    ->parse('@AcmeBundle/Resources/dart/AcmeMain/web/main.dart')
    ->getPath()
```

Like I asked in my question I wanted to use the `@` annotation.

Comment: This still produces the @ annotation. Can you advise how to get the URL!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this:

```
$this->container
->get('templating.helper.assets')
->getUrl('bundles/acmemy/public/image/myimage.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the twig asset helper:

```
$twig = clone $this->get('twig');
$twig->setLoader(new \Twig_Loader_String());
$rendered = $twig->render(
    '{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost ~ asset("bundles/acmemy/image/myimage.jpg") }}'
);
//Outputs - http://example.com/acmemybundle/images/myimage.jpg
```

OR you should even be able to do:

```
$twig = clone $this->get('twig');
$twig->setLoader(new \Twig_Loader_String());
$rendered = $twig->render(
    '{% image "@AcmeMyBundle/Resources/public/image/myimage.jpg" %}
     {{ asset_url }}
     {% endimage %}'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working in symfony 3 anymore

In symfony 3 use

```
$this->container->get('assets.packages')->getUrl($path);
```

Ex.

```
private function getAssets($path)
{
    return $this->container->get('assets.packages')->getUrl($path);
}

$this->getAssets(...your path...);
```